# Simple Speech Synthesis js crashes Chrome to Aw Snap screen

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-drive-api

I'm using a simple implementation of the Web Speech API, specifically Speech Synthesis.

It crashes chrome after saying the speech.

The page is being hosted in Google Drive.

Why does it crash chrome to the Aw Snap page? And how can I prevent / stop it?

Here is the URL: https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8QdcT0pIdGRmcjB5NkE/index.html

Here is the javascript:

```
function speak(whatToSay){
    if('speechSynthesis' in window){
        var speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(whatToSay);
        window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
    }
}
speak('Hello, World!');
```

Comment: That's odd because it works fine in the dev console but it does crash in the browser.

Comment: @NickFlekerFelker yes, it seems like a strange bug.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue, so have reported the bug using the url you posted.

You can track it here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=360370